# react-navigation TabNavigator Not render Next screen ,

Tags: react-native, navigation

First I have created a login, registration then HomeView (`TabBar`) screen, 
In App.js I have to create `StackNavigator`.

```
import HomeView from './AllViewController/HomeView';
import Login from './AllViewController/Login';
import Registration from './AllViewController/Registration';
import AlbumDetail from './AllViewController/AlbumDetail';
const RootStack = StackNavigator({

  Home: {screen: HomeView, navigationOptions: { header: null}},
  Login: {screen: Login, navigationOptions: { header: null}},
  Registration: {screen: Registration, navigationOptions: { header: null}},
  AlbumDetail: {screen: AlbumDetail, navigationOptions: { header: null}},
```

Home screen I have created `TabNavigator`  There I have showing four screen Album, Cart, Library, History screen. Problem is from album screen I am try to open new screen it's not working
Here is my Home screen code

```
import objAlbum from '../AllViewController/Album'
import objCart from '../AllViewController/Cart'
import objLibrary from '../AllViewController/Library'
import objHistory from '../AllViewController/History'
import {TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

const RootStack = TabNavigator({

    ClassA: { screen: objAlbum},
    ClassB: { screen: objLibrary },
    ClassC: { screen: objCart},
    ClassD: { screen: objHistory },

  })
  export default class HomeView extends Component {
    render() {
      return <RootStack />;
  }
  }
```

From Album screen I am trying to open `AlbumDetail` Screen is not working Please help me.

```
export default class Album extends Component<Props> {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            textInputData: "",
            textInputpassword: ""
          }


        this.click_Next = this.click_Next.bind(this);
    }


    click_Next = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('AlbumDetail')
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your two navigators are not linked between them.

First you should use a SwitchNavigator (instead of the stackNavigator) for your Login Screen. It is better for user experience and for your code later when you go back to your first state.

Then you could do that :

```
import objAlbum from '../AllViewController/Album'
import objCart from '../AllViewController/Cart'
import objLibrary from '../AllViewController/Library'
import objHistory from '../AllViewController/History'
import {TabNavigator, StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import Login from './AllViewController/Login';
import Registration from './AllViewController/Registration';
import AlbumDetail from './AllViewController/AlbumDetail';

const HomeView = TabNavigator({

 ClassA: { screen: objAlbum},
 ClassB: { screen: objLibrary },
 ClassC: { screen: objCart},
 ClassD: { screen: objHistory },

})

const RootStack = StackNavigator({

Home: {screen: HomeView, navigationOptions: { header: null}},
Login: {screen: Login, navigationOptions: { header: null}},
Registration: {screen: Registration, navigationOptions: { header: null}},
AlbumDetail: {screen: AlbumDetail, navigationOptions: { header: null}},
```